# Get all unique clients of groups of current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

A current_user has one or more groups. A group has one or more clients.

How can I get all the clients from all the groups from the current_user in a workable array?

I've got the method below working(I think properly)

```
  def clients_from_all_related_groups
    @clients = []
    current_user.groups.each do |c|
      @clients << c.clients
    end
  end
```

But when I try to each through them in my View I get the following output in HTML:

```
<a href="/clients/%23%3CActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy_Client:0x5f9b200%3E">Client</a>
```

This is the same when I use `@clients.to_a.push` or `@clients.push`.

I guess that the moment that I push the clients into a new array I break the rails-way of saving the objects.

How can I get it to work properly?

Comment: Try to use uniq_by(&:column_name) for associated objects.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `c.clients` is an association, not an array. It's only when you call methods on that association (such as `.all` or `.each`) that the records are actually fetched into something over which you can iterate (such as an `Array`).

Try the following to see if you get different results:

```
...

current_user.groups.each do |c|
  @clients << c.clients.all
end

@clients.uniq!    # This removes duplicates

...
```

Associations are often used in Rails to iterate over a list, such as a list of clients in a view. In that case you'd probably see something like:

```
# Just doing this from memory, not guaranteed to be perfect:

<% @group.clients.each do |c| %>
   <%= render partial: 'client'. locals: { client: c } %>
<% end %>
```

But in this case `.each` has been called on `@group.clients`, which is an association that, when you call `.each` on it gives back something over which you can iterate.

#### Side note:

There are ways to do load only the unique list of clients via SQL directly on the database. If you're feeling adventurous you could look into the query necessary to get just the unique client list directly from the DB, as an array of `Client` objects, rather than building the list in Ruby, which will generate a DB hit for every group at least. It may not matter in your particular case, but it's a good thing to know.